# C# Generic Polymorphism

Tags: c#, oop, generics, polymorphism

Assume there's a base class like this called a `Cup`:

```
public abstract class Cup { }
```

And let's assume there're `PaperCup` inheriting `Cup` and `PlasticCup` that inherits the `PaperCup` class.

```
public class PlasticCup : PaperCup { }
public class PaperCup : Cup { }
```

And assume that there're two methods in Main class.

```
static void Test01 (PaperCup cup) { }
static void Test02 (Cup cup) { }
```

---

### **TEST1**

```
PaperCup A = new PaperCup();
Test01(A);
Test02(A);
```

Above code works fine. `A` instance can be passed into those two function because it is `PaperCup` itself and it inheris `Cup` base class.

### TEST2

```
PlasticCup B = new PlasticCup();
Test01(B);
Test02(B);
```

Above code still works fine. `B` instance also is able to be taken by the functions although it is `PlasticCup` but it inheris `PaperCup` and it is eventually derived from `Cup`.

### But Generics !!

Let's see following methods.

```
static void Test010 (IList<PaperCup> cup) { }
static void Test011(IList<PlasticCup> cup) { }
static void Test012(IList<Cup> cup) { }
```

And this trial below will fail at two method calls.

```
IList<PlasticCup> BB = new List<PlasticCup>();
Test010(BB); // Fail CS1503 Compiler Error
Test011(BB);
Test012(BB); // Fail CS1503 Compiler Error
```

---

### Simple Question

Why is it impossible to pass the derived types into those functions when they take `Generic`? isn't it supposed to work because C# is an OOP language?

Comment: Covariance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: "because C# is an OOP language?" I wonder how you got to this conclusion. C# is a multi-paradigm language, even a functional one.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's not a great update imo, if you're going to edit, it's almost never a good idea to change code.

Comment: @DavidG How so? I removed only the completely irrelevant code, making the question much shorter.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It would only take a very small change to the question for that code to become relevant though. The code caused no harm and removing it was wasteful.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for the link. The doc explains everything I was confused about. I should dig C# into harder I guess.

Comment: @hina10531 I think covariance/contravariance is probably one of the least known things about C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, imagine the following were allowed:

```
IList<Cup> plasticCups = new List<PlasticCup>();
```

Then the following would be possible:

```
plasticCups.Add(new PaperCup()); //ouch!
```

And you've just inserted a paper cup in a plastic cup list. That doesn't seem right.

What you are asking about is [generic type variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). `IList<T>` is *invariant* in `T` because any other option (covariant or contravariant) would be *unsafe*.

C# *does* allow generic type variance in interfaces and delegates but only when the compiler can make sure its safe.

For instance `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant in `T` because you can't insert a paper cup into an `IEnumerable<PlasticCup>` (the rule is really that the type `T` is never used as a method argument), so the following is perfectly safe and will compile:

```
IEnumerable<Cup> plasticCups = Enumerable.Empty<PlasticCup>();
```

Its interesting to note that due to "supporting other existing language features" reasons when C# was born, arrays also support type variance but its completely broken. With arrays this is perfectly legal:

```
object[] strings = new string[] { .... }
strings[0] = new object(); //oh oh
```

And you will get an unfortunate runtime exception. With generics this can't happen.

Comment: Minor point: It's not about "inserting" `T` into the generic type, it's about the generic type taking the type as an input. So yes, that could be the `Add` method, but it could be anything else.

Comment: @DavidG good point! Adding is just the obvious example but yes, a `Find(T t)` would be equally unsafe.

Comment: This is also a dupe but I'm trying to figure out the best target! :)